# JavaFX FileChooser in BorderPane

Tags: javafx

Well, the title says it all, I'm trying to display a BorderPane in the "center" spot of a BorderPane. As I have no idea how to approach this or how JavaFX works, I have not managed to even try anything. So, I'd like to ask if this is even possible. Is there anyone who has done this before? Thanks in advane!

Comment: *I'm trying to display a BorderPane in the "center" spot of a BorderPane.* Do you mean `FileChooser`?

Comment: Normally, you programmatically open a `FileChooser` in another window.

Comment: A [FileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html) is not a graphic node like, for example, `TextField` is. You "display" a `FileChooser` by calling its `showOpenDialog()` method. Hence you can't add it to a container like `BorderPane`. Are you trying to display a list of files and directories?

Comment: Ok, thanks. Then I'll do it another way. I just thought this might look cool.